# ArcPy saveACopy method saving copy of MXD to wrong path?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I have a script that looks through datasets in a geodatabase and copies a mxd document to a folder. The programs works, however it is saving the map documents to my desktop and not the specified folder on my desktop (PATH2).
This is the code I have so far:

```
import arcpy
import os
PATH1 = r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT\DFM.gdb"
PATH2 = r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT\"
arcpy.env.workspace = PATH1
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

zones = arcpy.ListDatasets("Zone*")

for zone in zones:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT\Complete Final Capstone Map\Complete Z2 Campus Map_Landscape1.mxd")
    print zone
    mxd.saveACopy(PATH2 + zone)
```

Comment: I realised its recognising the path only as r""C:/Users/Daimon Nurse/Desktop" and using DFMPROJECT as part of the name of the  map document and not as the folder path

Comment: You just need to add another forward slash to the PATH2.

Comment: Do you mean as the edit I made to PATH2?

Comment: Personally, I would replace the backslash before a close-parenthesis with a forward slash, as I get errors in my IDE with `\"`, even with the r at the start of the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would set the PATH2 variable this way:

```
PATH2 = r"C:\Users\Daimon Nurse\Desktop\DFMPROJECT"
```

And then try this insead of `mxd.saveACopy(PATH2 + zone)`:

```
newmxd = os.path.join (PATH2, zone + ".mxd")
mxd.saveACopy(newmxd)
```